# how to add more than one object to FormData

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, rest

I am able to upload an image just fine.  However, I need to send a json object with the image so that I can identify what record the image belongs to.  What am I doing wrong?  Why does the variable info come through as null on the java side of the service?

Client:

```
let file = event.target.files[0];
 let info = {formId:8, formVersionId:2, formIndex:0};
var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            formData.append('info', info );
            $.ajax({
                url: URL.BUILDER_URL + '/megaUpload',
                type: 'POST',
                data : formData,
                cache : false,
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
            });
```

server:

```
public Response uploadFile( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, 
                                @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
                                @FormDataParam("info") GuiCreateResponse info) {
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the content type be "multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: When I change it to multipart/form-data, The service bombs out with a bad request error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Here it clearly states that ,
FormData value can either be a string or a blob.

```
let file = event.target.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            formData.append('formId', '8' );
            formData.append('formVersionId', '2' );
            formData.append('formIndex', '0');
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Closer.  On the server side, I set up this parameter in the rest method  "@FormDataParam("formId") FormDataContentDisposition form".  the variable form is populated, but the value '8' is nowhere to be found in the object.

Comment: Nailed it!  The issue I had on the server side what that I didn't have the right data type declared.  I needed it declared as a String. I needed this code:   @FormDataParam("formId") String form

Answer (score 0):

You are using `formId`, but you likely want to surround it in quotes as `"formId"`. Try this code.

```
let file = event.target.files[0];
let info = {"formId":8, "formVersionId":2, "formIndex":0}; //See changes here
var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            formData.append('info', info );
            $.ajax({
                url: URL.BUILDER_URL + '/megaUpload',
                type: 'POST',
                data : formData,
                cache : false,
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
            });
```

Comment: info is no longer null, but now its value is: <error(s)_during_the_evaluation>

Comment: Perhaps the answer above is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your issue.  The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) say, "When using the append() method it is possible to use the third optional parameter to pass a filename inside the Content-Disposition header that is sent to the server. When no filename is specified (or the parameter isn't supported), the name "blob" is used."

Since you do not provide a third parameter, I'm thinking the FormDataContentDisposition needs to look for "blob".  Try changing your server annotations to check for that name:

```
public Response uploadFile( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, 
                            @FormDataParam("blob") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
                            @FormDataParam("info") GuiCreateResponse info)
```